# How can I filter on different exceptions using only the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In the exception chooser (CTRL+ALT+E) in Visual Studio, how can I navigate this screen using the keyboard? So far TAB hasn't gotten me very far. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate through the buttons on the right side and eventually into the main pane.  When the main pane is selected, the OK button is highlit in blue, but doesn't have the line of dots surrounding it.

Once in the main part, you can navigate around the options using the arrow keys, and you can select/deselect options using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>